# Is this a correct usage of Event Aggregation?

Tags: c#, mvvm, observablecollection, caliburn.micro, eventaggregator

Dear Stackoverflow users,

I am currently developing a application that uses the MVVM pattern together with Caliburn micro.

I faced my first situation where I needed a dialog to be opened which would do some modifications to a ObservableCollection that needed to be visible on my main viewmodel.

I found out about event aggregation for my first time and thought that it would suite my situation. I am however not quite sure if event aggregation is the best solution or if I am using correctly... Therefore my question.

*Please keep in mind that the namespaces are left there intentionally incase I got it all wrong.*

The setup looks like this:

```
namespace Company.Product.Presentation.Core.Events
{
    public class PersonCollectionChanged
    {
        [CanBeNull]
        public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonCollection { get; set; }

        public PersonCollectionChanged(ObservableCollection<Person> personCollection)
        {
            PersonCollection = personCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel for the dialog

```
 namespace Company.Product.Presentation.Modules.Selection
{
    public class SelectionViewModel : Screen
    {
        private readonly IViewModelLoader _viewModelLoader;
        private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

        private readonly ObservableCollection<Person> _tempPersonCollection; 

        private readonly PersonCollectionChanged _personCollectionChanged;

        public SelectionViewModel(IViewModelLoader viewModelLoader, 
            IEventAggregator eventAggregator, 
            PersonCollectionChanged personCollectionChanged, 
            ObservableCollection<Person> tempPersonCollection)
        {
            _viewModelLoader = viewModelLoader;
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            _personCollectionChanged = personCollectionChanged;
            _tempPersonCollection = tempPersonCollection;

            AddPerson(new Person{Name = "Zatixiz"});

            _personCollectionChanged.PersonCollection = _tempPersonCollection;

            _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(_personCollectionChanged);
        }

        internal void AddPerson(Person person)
        {
            _tempPersonCollection.Add(person);
        }
    }
}
```

Main viewmodel subscribing to the event:

```
namespace Company.Product.Presentation.Modules.Main
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel, IHandle<PersonCollectionChanged>
    {

        private ObservableCollection<Person> _mainPersonCollection;

        public MainViewModel(
            IViewModelLoader viewModelLoader,
            IEventAggregator eventAggregator,
            ObservableCollection<Person> mainPersonCollection) : base(viewModelLoader)
        {
            _mainPersonCOllection = mainPersonCollection;

            eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);

        }

        public void Handle(PersonCollectionChanged message)
        {
            _mainPersonCollection = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the process of renaming my classes to examples. I forgot about StringCollection being an actual class haha.. I am chaning this!

Comment: What is responsible for creating these view models?

Comment: @MikeEason I have a custom ViewModelLoader which uses the Caliburn micro's WindowManager to open view models and is used like this:

_viewModelLoader.OpenDialog<SelectionViewModel>();

I hope that's what you wanted to know?

Comment: I don't see anything that would be bad other than not using `OnDeactivate()` to unsub the eventAggregator in the dialog. You can get some really weird behavior that would totally be undesirable and hard to ferret out debugging latter.